# delphi JvPasswordForm1

Tags: delphi, jvcl

hello experts
I had an old JVC components with **JvPasswordForm1**.

It seems this component **does not exist any more: what component is it replaced by** ?

reagrds

Comment: With 26% of accepted answers, you should really accept the proposed solution (with 3 votes up today) or post a comment !

Answer (score 3):

Try look for `TJvLoginDialog`, `TjvPassword` has merged into it.